# SymPy Return False for Eq.solve

Tags: python, math, jupyter-notebook, sympy, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this out the long way rather than use M.eigenvects(), and I haven't been able to figure out how to set up the equation for variable eigenvector values, and then solve for them. I believe it has to do with the ability to allow one eigenvector component to vary and then find the related b1 for that eigenvector. I did try to say,

```py
a1 = 1
```

but I had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am also new to python so any side advice would be great too!

Here are my imports and first part to my code:

```
import sympy as sp
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np

x1, x2, m, k, , λ = sp.symbols('x1, x2, m, k, , λ')

M = sp.Matrix([ [ m ,  0 ],
                [ 0 , 2*m] ])

K = sp.Matrix([ [ -2*k ,   k ],
                [   k  , -2*k] ])

Minv = M.inv()

#forming our matrix
Matrix = - Minv * K

I = sp.eye( 2 )


Matrix_eqn = - Minv * K - I * **2

det_chara = sp.det( Matrix_eqn ).simplify()    # determinant of M^-1K-w^2I

det_chara_eqn = sp.Eq(det_chara, 0)            # creates an equation = to 0
display(det_chara_eqn)

#det_chara_eqn = det_chara_eqn.subs(  , sp.sqrt(λ) ) # sympy subs in  for sp.sqrt(λ)

2 = sp.solve(det_chara_eqn, **2)             #solves the equation for lambda
2
```

This outputs,

[image]

Here is the second part after finding the eigenvalues:

```
   # Finding 1st eigenvector related to ^2
   a1, b1, a2, b2 = sp.symbols(' a1, b1, a2, b2')


   Matrix_eqn_vec1 = - Minv * K - I * 2[0]                  # taking eigenvalue 1
   Matrix_eqn_vec1 = Matrix_eqn_vec1 * sp.Matrix( [a1, b1] ) # taking our eigenvector values
   display( Matrix_eqn_vec1 )

   sp.Eq(Matrix_eqn_vec1, 0)
```

Which returns,

[image]

Comment: I did not know this, I will fix this right away

Comment: You seem to be comparing a matrix (vector) with a number (zero).  Maybe you want to compare with a similar matrix of zeros?